# slick schema leftJoin produce Cartesian product

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, scalaquery

I have this two tables :

```
    select * from "DEPARTMENTS";
 ID | NAME  | MANAGER_ID 
----+-------+------------
  1 | FOO   |          1
  3 | XXX   |          2
  4 | dept1 |           
(3 rows)

select * from "EMPLOYEES";
 NAME | LAST |      EMAIL       | PHONE | SKYPE | DEPT_ID | ID 
------+------+------------------+-------+-------+---------+----
 AAA  | xxxx | abcdef@gmail.com |       |       |         |  1
 BBB  | yyyy |                  |       |       |         |  2
(2 rows)
```

**I want to get all departments with manager's name (if manager exists) total of 3 rows .**

however in my schema when I do:

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import play.api.Play.current
case class DepartmentManager(id:Int,name:String,manager:String="")
case class Department(id:Option[Int],name:String,managerId:Option[Int])
class Departments (tag: Tag) extends Table[Department](tag, "DEPARTMENTS") {
  val employees = TableQuery[Employees]
  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("NAME", O.NotNull)
  def managerId = column[Int]("MANAGER_ID", O.Nullable)
  def manager = foreignKey("EMP_FK",managerId,employees)(_.id)
  def * = (id.?,name,managerId.?) <> (Department.tupled, Department.unapply)
}

object Departments{
  val db = play.api.db.slick.DB
  val departments = TableQuery[Departments]
//this is the problematic query
  def allWithMngr = db.withSession { implicit session =>
    val employees = TableQuery[Employees]
    val dm = (departments leftJoin employees ).list
    dm.map(x =>DepartmentManager(x._1.id.getOrElse(0),x._1.name, x._2.name + " " + x._2.last))
  }
}
```

I am getting Cartesian product (dm.size = 6 )

trying to query like this:

```
val dm = (departments leftJoin employees on((a,b)=> a.id === b.id)).list
```

result an error:

> [SlickException: Read NULL value (null) for ResultSet column Path
>   s2._4]

This is my employees model:

```
case class Employee(name: String,last: String,email:Option[String]=None,phone:Option[String]=None,skype:Option[String]=None,department: Option[Int] = None, id: Option[Int] = None)
class Employees (tag: Tag) extends Table[Employee](tag, "EMPLOYEES") {
  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("NAME", O.NotNull)
  def last = column[String]("LAST", O.NotNull)
  def email = column[String]("EMAIL", O.Nullable)
  def phone = column[String]("PHONE", O.Nullable)
  def skype = column[String]("SKYPE", O.Nullable)
  def deptId = column[Int]("DEPT_ID", O.Nullable)
  def dept = foreignKey("EMP_FK",deptId,departments)(_.id)
  def * = (name,last,email.?,phone.?,skype.?,deptId.?, id.?) <> (Employee.tupled, Employee.unapply)
val departments = TableQuery[Departments]

}
```

as Output I want the equivalent to this native Sql :

```
val query =sql""" select x."ID", x."NAME", y."NAME" from "DEPARTMENTS" x  LEFT OUTER JOIN "EMPLOYEES" y ON (x."MANAGER_ID" = y."ID");""".as[DepartmentManager].list
```

which will result :

```
List (DepartmentManager(1,"FOO","AAA"),DepartmentManager(3,"XXX","BBB"),DepartmentManager(4,"FOO",""))
```

Comment: Can you give the example output of what you want in table form?

Comment: Off-Topic: If the db design is not yet settled I'd suggest to use relation tables instead of nullable foreign keys. That saves you from some edge cases and eases querying.

Comment: @Jus12 I did now, thanks for your comment

Comment: A table format will be more helpful in addition to your SQL. What we need is the actual query and the data returned.

Comment: @Jus12 it is actually there below the query - List(DepartmentManager(...

Comment: @igx oh yes I missed that. Used to seeing this in table format. Suggest you to put in table format as you did in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're running into here is the awkward way Slick 2 deals with nulls in joins. Things are better in Slick 3, but we can get the join to work in Slick 2.

The query you have...

```
(departments leftJoin employees ).list
```

...will be a cross join as you don't have a `join`.

The error you run into when you use the `join` is because one of the columns you want to select is NULL.  With Slick 2 you have to explicitly pick out these columns and promote them with `.?` to an option:

```
val query = 
   departments.leftJoin(employees).on(_.managerId === _.id )
              .map { case (d, e) => (d.id, d.name, e.name.?) }
```

Note the `e.name.?` --- because there might not be an `e` (employee) for the department.

The result of this query with your test data is:

```
(1, FOO,   Some(AAA))
(2, XXX,   Some(BBB))
(3, dept1, None)
```

...which I think is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. much more clear now